# using global for dependency with grunt-browserify

Tags: d3.js, gruntjs, browserify, yepnope, dynamic-script-loading

I'm using `yepnope` to load scripts conditionally, based on some tests, and I'm also using `browserify`, via `grunt-browserify` to build my scripts. Now I want one script to replace the other, but still be called via the same require:

```
// if svg support, then d3.js, otherwise r2d3.js
var d3 = require('d3');
```

So `d3` is used as a require in my code, and also as a dependency for another lib.

The issue is that it can't be done with different require statements, because those are done during the build and the test can't happen because it depends on the users browser.

So I need a way to specify that the dependency uses `d3` from `window.d3`, so I can set the window object with either of the libs. This is my grunt-browserify config..

```
options: {
  external: ['d3'],
  shim: {
    'd3-chart': {
       path: 'assets/bower_components/d3.chart/d3.chart.js',
       exports: null,
       depends: {
         d3: 'd3'
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I get `Cannot find module 'd3'` when r2d3 is loaded, even though that exports a [window.d3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/blob/master/r2d3.js#L6691).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to Browserify, if you are using Browserify 3.0 you are able to [utilize the browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/#you-will-always) as a transform, and expose a [global reference](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/tree/master/examples/expose-jquery) to d3 by sticking a reference to D3 in your package.json like so:

```
 "browserify-shim": {
   "d3": "global:d3"
 }
```

After [installing the shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#1-install-browserify-shim-dependency) will need to add a transform for the browserify-shim if you have not already

```
options: {
  transform: ['browserify-shim']
}
```

I wasn't able to confirm that this worked correctly in my build, as I discovered [an alternate solution to my problem](https://www.npmjs.org/package/browserify-xcharts) (I'm using xCharts).  (Furthermore, I just switched to gulp.)

Comment: I think global: actually skips parsing the dependency into the bundle. I'll come back and edit this; I'm refactoring my app with "real" data today...

Comment: I can't seem to suggest an edit to your answer. Line 2 should be "d3": "global:d3". The d3 global has a lowercase "d".

Comment: Thanks @Dominick! I had the same problem on another post; it won't let you edit if it's under so many characters. I've applied your edit.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple ways to handle this with browserify.

1.) You could use load in your D3 libraries conditionally outside of browserify and create a file that:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = window.D3
```

then when you are using D3 chart in your code require that file.

2.)The other way could be to use promethify, where you could conditionally require this.
https://github.com/johnkpaul/promethify

3.) You can manually shim it by exporting a function that takes d3 as the param:

```
https://gist.github.com/michaelBenin/9557281
var d3 = window.d3;
require('../d3-plugin/d3.chart.js')(d3);
```

4.) You could have 2 browserify builds, one for legacy, one for modern.

I'd go with option 3 and pass in window.d3 as the argument.

Update: Also checkout exposify instead of using window.D3 https://github.com/thlorenz/exposify